# How can one tell if a variable value is a number in TCL?

Tags: numbers, tcl, number-formatting

I want to check if an input is a valid number or not in Tcl.
I.e.:
1.2.0 is not.
 1.20 is.
1e-9 is
-00.61 is.
1.91e-a0 is not.
I could not find a good answer on the web.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string is double $myNum
```

Returns 1 if it's a valid number, otherwise 0. Note that the empty string is considered a valid number unless you give the `-strict` option:

```
string is double -strict $myNum
```

Documentation: [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)